Spectrum of isometry in Banach space
Recently I met the following
Fact: If $T$ is an isometry of Banach space $X$ then either $\ \sigma(T)\subset \mathbb T\ $ or $\ \sigma(T)=\overline{\mathbb D}\ $,  where $\sigma$ stends for spectrum, $\ \mathbb T\ $ and $\overline{\mathbb D}$ denote unit circle and closed unit disc, respectively.
First of all, clearly $\sigma(T)\subset \overline{\mathbb D}=\{|z|\le \|T\|\}.$ In this question it's explained why $\sigma(T)\subset \mathbb T\ $ if $\ T$ is invertible.
Now let's say $T$ is not invertible, i. e. $0\in \sigma(T).$ Why then $\lambda\in \sigma(T)$ for any $|\lambda|\le 1$? The explanation I found in one of the discussions I belive is a bit overcomplicated. May be there is another way?
Thank you!

While it seems a bit roundabout at first glance, it's still short enough that there could be no simpler/more elementary way to prove it. Especially since there's no "simple" characterisation for the shapes of spectra, even just for connected ones ("the spectrum is connected iff the Banach algebra generated by the operator and the identity has no nontrivial idempotents" isn't exactly practical nor elementary...).
